# JSON.parse not creating a json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, serialization

I am getting below string from upstream. Have no control over it.

```
b"{'text': 'Airtel Tower (@ BT Tower in Chasdmzoa, Delhi)', 'sentiment': '0.25'}"
```

I want to change the string to JSON. So the first thing I did was removing preceeding b'....' (upstream is a python program that produces utf-8 string as an output). So I am removing 'b' using substr..

```
str = msg.payload.substr(1);
```

Then I am trying to convert the string to JSON using **JSON.stringify** and **JSON.parse**.

```
console.log(typeof(str));
var t = JSON.stringify(str);
console.log(typeof(t));
var t = JSON.parse(t);
console.log("First:  " + t);
var t = JSON.parse(t);
console.log("Second  " + t);
x = t.text;
y = t["text"];
console.log(x + " ---- " + y);
```

***Console Output:***

```
string
string
First:  "{'text': 'Airtel Tower(@ KT Tower in Bang, Greater K
n), 'sentiment': '0.25'}"
Second  {'text': 'Vodafone Tower (@ LT Tower in Delhi, Greater K
), 'sentiment': '0.25'}
undefined ---- undefined
```

It fails to convert it to object even though **JSON.stringify** removed the extra quotes etc. and **JSON.parse** doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You also have to replace `'` with `"` since JSON only supports double quotes.

Comment: isn't your `Airtel Tower (@ BT Tower in Chasdmzoa, Delhi)'` missing a single quote `'` at the start?

Comment: I dont know wht 1 up vote since the data in question itself is wrong

Comment: I removed the missing single quote while copying by mistake. Updated now. @molamk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const input = "b'\"{'text': 'Airtel Tower (@ BT Tower in Chasdmzoa, Delhi)', 'sentiment': '0.25'}\"'";

const cleanString = str => str.split('"')[1].replace(/'/g, '"');

console.log(input);

// Result
console.log(JSON.parse(cleanString(input)));
```

## Explanation

1. [Split the string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with the *double quote* `"` as a delimiter
2. Get the second item. This will give you `{'text': 'Airtel Tower (@ BT Tower in Chasdmzoa, Delhi)', 'sentiment': '0.25'}`
3. [Replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) *single quotes* `'` with *double quotes* `"`. This will give you `{"text": "Airtel Tower (@ BT Tower in Chasdmzoa, Delhi)", "sentiment": "0.25"}`
4. Call [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) on the previous string to have your object

Comment: The explanation helped.

Answer (score 1):

There's an issue here: single-quoted string literals aren't valid JSON. JSON is based on JavaScript, but it's not the same thing. If you're writing an object literal inside JavaScript code, fine; if you actually need JSON, you need to use ".

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer (for non-anti-`eval`-zealots):

```
var string = msg.payload.substring(3,msg.payload.length-2);
var t = eval("(" + string + ")");
```

If you can't stand, or can't use (strict mode?), `eval`, then you need to convert the single quotes to double quotes for parsing, as JSON only accepts double quotes:

```
var string = msg.payload.substring(3,msg.payload.length-2);
var t = JSON.parse(string.replace(/'/g, "\""));
```